# ModuleNotFoundError when using a function from a custom module that imports another custom module

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, runtime-error, python-import

I have a folder structure similar to this (my example has all the necessary bits):

```
web-scraper/
    scraper.py
    modules/
        __init__.py
        config.py
        website_one_scraper.py
```

Where `config.py` just stores some global variables. It looks a bit like:

```
global var1
var1 = "This is a test!"
```

Within `website_one_scraper.py` it looks like this:

```
import config

def test_function():
    # Do some web stuff...
    return = len(config.var1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(test_function)
```

And `scraper.py` looks like this:

```
from module import website_one_scraper

print(website_one_scraper.test_function())
```

`website_scraper_one.py` works fine when run by itself, and thus the code under `if __name__ == "__main__"` is run. However, when I run `scraper.py`, I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

And this is the full error and traceback (albeit with different names, as I've changed some names for the example above):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\User\Documents\Programming\Work\intrack-web-scraper\satellite_scraper.py", line 3, in 
<module>
from modules import planet4589
File "c:\Users\User\Documents\Programming\Work\intrack-web-scraper\modules\planet4589.py", line 5, in 
<module>
import config
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

Also note that In `scraper.py` I've tried replacing `from modules import website_one_scraper` with `import website_one_scraper`, `from .modules import website_one_scraper`, and `from . import website_one_scraper`, but they all don't work.

What could the cause of my error be? Could it be something to do with how I'm importing everything?

(I'm using Python 3.9.1)

Answer (score 1):

In your `website_scraper_one.py`, instead of `import config.py` try to use `from . import config`

**Explanation**:

- . is the current package or the current folder
- config is the module to import

Comment: This creates the error `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` when running `website_scraper_one.py` directly...

Comment: Yes. It should give you the error. Inside `modules`, you created a python package, which has `relative imports` in it. So in this case, you have to run the `website_scraper_one.py` as a python module, by `python -m modules.website_scraper_one`, and this will solve the issue. Thanks